# Python get ket from value explanation

Tags: python, dictionary

I found code to get the key from the value in the python dictionary.

```
mydict = {'george': 16, 'amber': 19}
print(list(mydict.keys())[list(mydict.values()).index(16)])
```

I am really new to python and could somebody explain it by breaking it down by components?

Answer (score 2):

**You can use a python interpreter to break it down.**

Like this,

Values of dictionary

```
In [1]: mydict.values()
Out[1]: dict_values([16, 19])
```

Finding the index of `16`

```
In [2]: list(mydict.values()).index(16)
Out[2]: 0
```

Keys of dictionary and converted them to list

```
In [3]: list(mydict.keys())
Out[3]: ['george', 'amber']
```

Fetching the `0`th element from list

```
In [4]: list(mydict.keys())[0]
Out[4]: 'george'
```